# calculating program's runtime for each iteration using Unix program time

Tags: c++, bash, shell, unix, runtime

I wish to calculate runtime of my program which approximates PI using Monte Carlo Method. I have written a unix shell script which feeds the program No of points, N = 10^{k} , for K = 1,2, ...7. 
Now I wish to find the execution time for Each N in Unix program time. My unix shell script looks as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash

k=1
N=10
while [[ k -le 7 ]]
do
    echo "$k N" | ./pi $N

    ((k = k + 1))
    ((N = N * 10))
done
```

Now when I type: `$ time ./pi.sh` , it returns me the total execution time

```
        10                 3.6            0.1459155902616465
       100                3.08           0.01960555055392467
      1000               3.104           0.01196611328551369
     10000              3.1284          0.004199352062629202
    100000              3.1432         0.0005116342528909465
   1000000            3.139704         0.0006011771092076384
  10000000            3.141432         5.113762588206346e-05

real    0m0.583s
user    0m0.560s
sys     0m0.012s
```

I was wondering if I have to write a bash script to get execution time for Each N input or I have to do something in my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By writing `$ time ./pi.sh` you are measuring time needed to execute pi.sh, which has a loop in it. So you measure total time for all iterations. If you want to measure every iteration independently, you have to put `time` in invocation of the iteration:

```
echo "$k N" | time ./pi $N
```

Comment: that works great! among the three time outputs I get, which one represents the program runtime?

Comment: "real" is a real word time spent. When app sleeps or when CPU is used by another app this timer still ticks. "user" is CPU time spent in user mode. "sys" is CPU time spent in kernel mode.

Comment: ok, what is that real runtime unit? How do I get that in seconds from unix script?

Comment: Units are given in the output of time utility: `0m0.583s` stands for 0 minutes and 0.583 seconds. There can be hours too. See `man time` for additional information and formatting options.